# How can I add multiple data to $.ajax()?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop, shopping-cart

Can anyone show the correct syntax for adding multiple data to the database. The code i`m using below only adds 1 data.. I already know what to do on the PHP side. I'am making this for a drag and drop shopping cart system.

```
function addlist(param)

 {
    $.ajax({ type:"POST",
url: "ajax/addtocart.php",
data: 'img='+encodeURIComponent(param),
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend:function(x){$('#ajax-loader').css('visibility','visible');},
success: function(msg){

    $('#ajax-loader').css('visibility','hidden')
               }

 });

}
```

Comment: look at serialization in ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
data: 'img='+encodeURIComponent(param),
```

with

```
data: {img:param, otherParam:otherValue},
```

and let jQuery do the encodings.

Comment: LOL. +1 for you. Nice answer, and 8 seconds apart.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data as an object to jQuery. Let it do the serialization for you:

```
data: { key: 'value', key2: 'value2' }
```